# Source request: Optimal bounds on signings of points from a convex body

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, discrepancy-theory

I recently came across an old survey of problems in discrete geometry: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c350/f4d4a9466fa6708d99ec1187c63d89bed20f.pdf

Problem 2.1 from the list caught my eye. It states the following (more or less):

Let $y_1, y_2, ... y_m \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $y_i \neq 0$. Let $K$ be the convex body consisting of all points $z = \sum_{i=1}^m c_i y_i$ for $c_i \in [-1, 1]$. Does there exists a universal constant $C$ such that given $x_1, x_2, ... x_k \in K$, there are signs $\delta_1, \delta_2, ... \delta_k \in \{-1,1\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k \delta_i x_i \in C \sqrt{k} K$?

Has any progress been made on this problem? I have not been able to find anything in the literature. Further, Schectman claims that a bound of $C \sqrt{k \log \log k}$ is possible: I have not been able to find this in the literature. Does anyone know a source for this claim?